# robocopy invalid parameter "-"

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, cmd

I am trying to complete my batch script but under certain circumstances it fails.

This is the command I am running:

```
ROBOCOPY "C:\test\dash2\Hello - 4\" "C:\test\dash2\Hello - 4\..\" /MOV
```

And this is the error I am getting

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Started : Mon May 11 01:28:46 2015

   Source - C:\test\dash2\Hello - 4" C:\test\dash2\Hello\
     Dest -

    Files :
  Options : /COPY:DAT /R:1000000 /W:30

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

ERROR : Invalid Parameter #2 : "-"
```

I do surround my source and destination by double quotes.
But according to the ROBOCOPY log the source and dest seems to be wrong

**EDIT**

It seems that it thinks the space is a separator, so it treats the "-" as the second parameter.

Comment: try to use single quote instead

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
ROBOCOPY "C:\test\dash2\Hello - 4\" "C:\test\dash2\Hello - 4\..\" /MOV
                                 ^                             ^
```

Remove the ending backslashes that are escaping the quotes

**edited** to adapt to comments

If source and destination are variables and removing the backslash is a problem, this can be used

```
robocopy "%source%\." "%target%\."
```

Comment: That seems to also work, but the source and destination are variables, so removing the trailing backslash might be more work than just escape last double quote.

Answer (score 1):

Well it seems that you have to escape the double quotes.
The trick is to only escape the second double quote

So the correct solutions was:

```
ROBOCOPY "C:\test\dash2\Hello - 4\/" "C:\test\dash2\Hello - 4\..\/" /MOV
```